# Troubleshooting JavaFX NoClassDefFoundError When Running JAR File: How to Include JavaFX in Gradle-built JAR?

Tags: java, gradle, jar, dependencies, noclassdeffounderror

Facing "NoClassDefFoundError" when running Gradle-generated JAR for JavaFX app. Gradle build succeeds, but JAR execution fails due to missing "javafx/application/Application" class. Need help including JavaFX in JAR build.

Here is the error:

> Error: Could not find or load main class com.jamal1aarab.Main
> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application

Here is part of my build file where I think the problem is:

```
mainClassName = 'com.jamal1aarab.Main'

jar {
  manifest {
    attributes(
      'Main-Class': 'com.jamal1aarab.Main'
    )
  }
}
```

The directory is correct at `src\main\java\com\jamal1aarab`

I configured my Gradle build with the main class and manifest attributes. Gradle build and run work fine, but when I try running the JAR, the "NoClassDefFoundError" pops up. I expected my JavaFX app to run smoothly from the JAR, just like it does through Gradle. However, the missing "javafx/application/Application" class caused the JAR execution to fail.

Also, I've come across numerous Stack Overflow posts discussing similar issues. However, most solutions seem to involve fixing the path, which I've already ensured is correct in my case.

Comment: You'd need to use something like [shadow](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow) but I think in the case of JavaFX, the smarter money would be on using `jpackage`

Comment: How do you exactly try to run the jar? Depending on the version of Java you use, you may have to add module path and javafx modules.

Comment: @CjY i run it normally using java -jar name.jar because i dont have javafx localy i add it using gradle

Comment: That is ... confusing. If you don't have it "locally" then I don't see how you run it at all as it's sure not in your jar (as your error shows)

Comment: @g00se thank you for the suggestion earlier
what confuse me is that gradle run the app successfully but when it comes to the jar file it dosent work

Comment: @CjY I tried using this but still no result :
java --module-path C:\programming\javafx-sdk-20.0.2\lib --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml -jar systemGestionConges.jar

Comment: *I tried using this...* You can't mix in `-jar`. That parameter is a stand-alone means of running a *self-sufficient* packaged jar. Yours is **not** self-sufficient as your default runtime doesn't have JavaFx. Therefore you either have to make it so, or run it specifying the main class and all its modules and or/classpaths

Comment: You still got the same error after adding the modules and path?

Comment: @cjy yes 
Error: Could not find or load main class com.jamal1aarab.Main